Create shopify flow for handeling metafields
I try to create a flow to add addressline2 to addressline1. But the workflow is unable to be activated. I'm also not sure if the any of the values is correct since I have no experience doing this. Anyone who knows how to handle metafields, maybe another way?
Please see sceenshots:
code
flow
